# Anything wrong with following analysis on $y=\tan(x+y)$?

Tags: functions, derivatives

Given $y=\tan(x+y)$, we want to discuss the derivative of $y$ of $x$, says $y'_x$.

Assume that $y$ is a function of $x$, then by $y(x)=\tan(x+y(x))$, the derivative of both sides remains equal,
$$y'_x=y'_x\sec^2(x+y),\tag{1}$$

then we get $y'_x=-\csc^2(x+y)$.

But if we analysis equation (1), we finds
$$y'_x\tan^2(x+y)=0,$$
so for any $x$, either $y'_x=0$ or $\tan(x+y)=0$.

We can easily deduce that neither $y'_x=0$ nor $\tan(x+y)=0$ can be hold on any open interval $(a,b)$:

1) If for any $x\in(a,b)$, $y'_x=0$, then $y=C$, where $C\in\mathbb{R}$ is a constant. From the original equation $y=\tan(x+y)$, we get
$$C=\tan(x+C),\;(x\in(a,b)).$$
It's obviously false.

2) If for any $x\in(a,b)$, $\tan(x+y)=0$, then we get $x+y=k\pi,\;k\in\mathbb{Z}$. From $y=\tan(x+y)$, we get $y=0$, that means $x=k\pi,\;k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $\tan(x+y)=0$ can only holds with some isolated $x$ values.

In conclusion, equation (1) can only holds on some isolated point $x$, is there anything wrong?

[image: Graph of $y=\tan(x+y)$]

From the graph above, we can find $y'_x$ could never be $0$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an error in determining the derivative of $\tan (x+y(x))$ as given in Equation $(1)$ of the OP.  Note that we have

$$y'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\tan (x+y)=\sec^2(x+y)\,(1+y'(x)) \tag{A}$$

Solving $(A)$ for $y'$ yields

$$\begin{align}
y'(x)&=\frac{\sec^2 (x+y(x))}{1-\sec^2 (x+y(x))}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x+y(x))-1}\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{\sin^2(x+y(x))}\\\\
&=-\csc^2(x+y(x))
\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes, I've just noticed that, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.